# why re.search print match found even string is not exact similar

Tags: python, regex

My `string_first` matches with both `pattern` and `pattern_second` (see code below). However, I would like for it to be matched only with `pattern_second`. Could someone help me in achieving this?

```
import re

string_first = "this-is-first-time"
pattern = "this-is-first"
pattern_second = "this-is-first.*"

if re.search(pattern, string_first):
    print("string match for pattern first")
else:
    print("string not match")

if re.search(pattern_second, string_first):
    print("string match for pattern second")
else:
    print("string not match")
```

Comment: `.*`  matches any **0 or more** chars (other than line break chars, by default). `a` will always find a match where`a.*` finds a match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In you pattern specify that you have the end of the line as follows:

```
pattern = "this-is-first$"
```

'$' means end of line.

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
import re

string_first = "this-is-first-time"
pattern = "this-is-first\s"
pattern_second = "this-is-first.*"

if re.search(pattern, string_first):
    print("string match for pattern first")
else:
    print("string not match")

if re.search(pattern_second, string_first):
    print("string match for pattern second")
else:
    print("string not match")
```

Output

```
string not match
string match for pattern second
```

Comment: want to match with pattern_second not pattern

Comment: Edited the code accordingly